# Adding a Calculator to a Wordpress Page

Tags: pages, jquery, css, javascript, html

I have a calculator written in HTML, CSS, JS and JQuery all in separate files and I am wondering how I would add this to a single page on a wordpress site? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is this for a theme or a plugin?

Comment: What is "single page"?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into creating a plugin for this and then inside of the plugin generating a shortcode for the output so you can place it almost anywhere you'd like inside wordpress.

Having it has a plugin will give you the flexibility of quickly making changes and the future chance to apply it easily to other sites.

Without seeing your code it's hard to give you a more detailed answer.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API